# How to get touch portion bitmap of image?

Tags: android

I am working on Bitmap. I have an image, Using touch listener I will get x and y axis values.
I have to get the finger touch portion's color of image. ie., on image, where ever I touch, I have to get the color of that touch portion of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `getPixel(int x, int y)` to do this. For more information, check [the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)` on your bitmap object. It will return you the int value from where you need to take out separate a,r,g,b values by shifting bits to the right:

```
int pixelCol = bmp.getPixel(touchX,touchY);

          int a = (pixelCol >>> 24) & 0xff;
          int r = (pixelCol >>> 16) & 0xff;
          int g = (pixelCol >>> 8) & 0xff;
          int b = pixelCol & 0xff;
```